# Convert danish numbers to english?

Tags: javascript

How do i convert a danish number to an english format 
for example :
8,5 is decimal number representation in danish 
and in english it would be 8.5 
Now i need to convert 8,5 to 8.5 my current culture is danish and i am trying to convert this in javascript (**NOT C#**)

Regards,
Francis P.

Comment: Can you not do this on the server-side?

Answer (score 2):

If it's in a string, you can just use:

```
newstr = oldstr.replace(/,/,".");
```

For example, head on over to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace) and enter:

```
<html><body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var oldstr="8,5";
        var newstr = oldstr.replace(/,/,".");
        document.write(newstr);
    </script>
</body></html>
```

to get:

```
8.5
```

If you want to *swap* the thousands separators and decimal point, it's a little bit trickier:

```
<html><body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var oldstr="1.472.318,5";
        var newstr = oldstr.replace(/,/,"xyzzy");
        newstr = newstr.replace(/\./g,",");
        newstr = newstr.replace(/xyzzy/,".");
        document.write(newstr);
    </script>
</body></html>
```

will give you:

```
1,472,318.5
```

If you want to intelligently figure out which separator is being used, that's even trickier. What I would do in that case is analyse the string for specific formats. Check how many of each of the `.` and `,` characters are and ensure the one with a count of one is treated as the decimal. But that will not work for edge cases like `1,500` - is that fifteen hundred or one point five?

What *I* would do then is simply put a big message on the web page along the lines of:

> Please ensure all amounts are entered in U.S. format (with comma for thousands separator and period for decimal point).

Sometimes you just have to tell the client what's right :-)

Comment: To do more than one (think thousands separator, which has this same problem), you need the global flag on that.

Comment: Thanks pax, But my application could culture cn be changed .that is i can select a culture of danish ,English

Comment: Well, just store the numbers in the English format (easier to deal with) and use the "English-to-Danish" conversion provided by @paxdiablo only if the user selected Danish.